# Cannot download and display images in swift at the same time

Tags: swift, image

Basically, I am working on a comic book app. when the user clicks on the volume, I want the volume to start displaying as soon as the first images downloads ( basically downloads the images and display them at the same time, and if the user is reading a page the others gets downloaded in the background). Currently, my app crashes, or is stuck until all the images are downloaded and added to the array from the loop I have.

```
 func updateView(){

    DispatchQueue.global().sync {
        for i in 0..<testArray1.count {
            let imgUrl = URL(string: testArray1[i])!

            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: imgUrl as URL)
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.imgArr.append(image)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information, I tried using SD-Webimages but I did not know how.

Thank you,

Comment: Try using asynchronous for downloads and synchronous when you update UI with images. Why does it crash? Are you getting and data back from url?

Comment: Loading data `sync`hronously is always bad, you are also discouraged from using `Data(contentsOf` to load data from a remote URL. I'm sure `SD-Webimages` provides better ways.

Comment: Yes I am getting everything back and all the images load at once but I wanna display them individually as they download when they are. @vadin can you help me with the right way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `SD-Webimages`